# Sharepoint Webpart with html Table using SPSERVICES

Tags: 2010, 2013, html, jquery-ui

Attached image

[image]

Has my SharePoint list data and the output which I want to achieve. Can you please help me to create the structure which is in the Image **Dynamically**  Also Next time when I try to add a new item it should come under the same category. Can you please help me to genrate the HTML table or by using DIV & LI tags and assign the same dynamically.

Here is my script where I am using SPservices to fetch the data.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">


//this is where the script starts after the page is loaded
$(document).ready(function() { 

    GetData();

});

function GetData()
{

        var method = "GetListItems";            
        var list = "ResourceList"
        var fieldsToRead =     "<ViewFields>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='URL' />" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='Category' />" +            
                            "</ViewFields>";                                   
        var query = "<Query>" +
                        "<Where>" +
                            "<Neq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>0</Value>" + 
                            "</Neq>" +
                        "</Where>" +
                        "<OrderBy>" + 
                            "<FieldRef Name='Category'/>" +
                        "</OrderBy>" +
                    "</Query>";

    var clientData = {};

    var liHtml="";
    var html="";


        $().SPServices({
                operation: method,
                async: false,  
                listName: list,
                CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,
                  CAMLQuery: query,

                    completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 

                        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {                                                                                                                                                                      
                            var Url = ($(this).attr("ows_URL")).split(",")[0];
                            var UrlDesc=($(this).attr("ows_URL")).split(",")[1];                                                        
                            var Category = ($(this).attr("ows_Category"));
                            if(clientData.hasOwnProperty(Category)){
                                clientData[Category] = clientData[Category] + "," + Url + "#" +UrlDesc;                               
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                clientData[Category] = Url + "#" +UrlDesc;
                            } 


                        });

                        console.log(clientData);
                     for (var category in clientData)
                     {
                         var category_attr;
                         category_attr = clientData[category];
                         category_attr = category_attr.split(",");

                          html = "<ul>" + category.trim() + "</ul>";
                         for(var i=0; i<category_attr.length; i++)
                         {
                             var temp = category_attr[i].split("#");
                             var url = temp[0].trim();
                             var urldesc = temp[1].trim();
                              liHtml += "<li>"+
                                     "<a href='" +url +"'>"+urldesc+""+"</a>"+
                                  "</li>";  
                         }
                         html = html + liHtml;
                         $("#tasksUL").append(html);
                     }
                       //$("#tasksUL").append(html); 
                    }
        });

}
</script>
<div id="tasksUL" ></div>
```

I made some progress and i was able to assign it to UL and LI tags.
**MY ORGINAL VIEW**
[image] 
 **OUTPUT OF THE CODE**
[image]
But the problem is when i try to loop through the array object the previous LI values get's appended to the next LI values.
Basically i am poor in UI so i was unable to get the Format which i have posted earlier. Any UI specialist help me on achieving this.

My array object clientdata is returning like this

```
Object { AUSTRALIA: "http://au.com# AU,http://mcg.com# MCG", INDIA: "http://kp.com# KP,http://ap.com# AP,http://tg.com# TG", PAKISTAN: "http://PK.COM# PK,http://POL# POL", USA: "http://UU# UU,http://PHL.com# PHL" }
```

**CLIENT DATA OBJECT DURING DEBUG**
[image]

Comment: hi sandy143 did you tried to solve your query? I am looking for the same rather...!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Full code how i have achieved this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


//this is where the script starts after the page is loaded
$(document).ready(function() { 

    GetData();

});
/*MAIN FUNCTION TO READ THE LIST ITEMS FROM TEH LIST USING SPSERVICES*/
function GetData()
{

        var method = "GetListItems";            
        var list = "ResourceList"
        var fieldsToRead =     "<ViewFields>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='URL' />" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='Category' />" +            
                            "</ViewFields>";                                   
        var query = "<Query>" +
                        "<Where>" +
                            "<Neq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>0</Value>" + 
                            "</Neq>" +
                        "</Where>" +
                        "<OrderBy>" + 
                            "<FieldRef Name='Category'/>" +
                        "</OrderBy>" +
                    "</Query>";

    var clientData = {};   
    var liHtml="";
    var html="";


        $().SPServices({
                operation: method,
                async: false,  
                listName: list,
                CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,
                  CAMLQuery: query,

                    completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 

                        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {                                                                                                                                                                      
                            var Url = ($(this).attr("ows_URL")).split(",")[0];
                            var UrlDesc=($(this).attr("ows_URL")).split(",")[1];                                                        
                            var Category = ($(this).attr("ows_Category"));
                            if(clientData.hasOwnProperty(Category)){
                                clientData[Category] = clientData[Category] + "," + Url + "#" +UrlDesc;                               
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                clientData[Category] = Url + "#" +UrlDesc;
                            } 


                        });
                      //  console.log(clientData);



                     for (var category in clientData)
                     {
                         var category_attr = [];
                        // console.log(category);
                         category_attr = clientData[category];
                         category_attr = category_attr.split(",");
                        // console.log(category_attr);
                          html = "<div style='float: left'><ul><li class='list-view'>" + category.trim() + "</li>";
                         liHtml = "";
                         for(var i=0; i<category_attr.length; i++)
                         {
                             var temp = category_attr[i].split("#");
                             var url = temp[0].trim();
                             var urldesc = temp[1].trim();
                              liHtml += "<li>"+
                                     "<a href='" +url +"'>"+urldesc+""+"</a>"+
                                  "</li>";  
                         }
                         html = html + liHtml + "</ul></div>";
                         $("#tasksUL").append(html);
                     }

                    }
        });

}
</script>
<style type="text/css" >    
#tasksUL ul{  width:350px;  }
#tasksUL ul li{ list-style: inside none square !important; padding-left:10px !important;   }
.list-view { background: #005898 !important; padding:2px; color:#FFF !important;   }
</style>
<div id="tasksUL" ></div>
```

Comment: This section is for answers only, please add this to your questions body instead

Comment: Robert i tried posting it in question section due to space constraint i have posted it here .